# cannot find local package in plugin

Tags: go

I am writing a plugin in Golang and I am trying to import a package, one level up from the plugin. But, I cannot possibly find the package.

The package name is: **com_styx_proto**

path of plugin: **SomeCoolUser/go/src/go_poc/plugins/styxBotDetectGrpc/styxBotDetectGrpc.go**

path of package trying to access: **SomeCoolUser/go/src/go_poc/plugins/styx.pb.go**

This code is not working:

```
import (
    "com_styx_proto"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

**Error when building**: cannot load go_poc/plugins: malformed module path "go_poc/plugins": missing dot in first path element

Comment: To downvoter: Where is a better suited place for this question?

Comment: You didn't provide a [mre], the steps to replicate, or even the error output you encountered. See [ask].

Comment: Updated. The reason why I didn't provide more code is because the error is in the import (which I provided)

Comment: The example wasn't missing `"Hello World!"`, the example is missing the exact steps you took to get the error. You're still listing specific files rather than packages. Neither `go_poc/plugins/styxBotDetectGrpc` nor `go_poc/plugins` is imported in the example (assuming you're using GOPATH). If you're not using GOPATH, how is the module setup?

Answer (score 1):

To import a package that is not part of the standard library, use its filesystem path. For your case, if you're trying to import the package under .../go_poc/plugins, write:

```
import (
   com_styx_proto "go_poc/plugins"
)
```

Also, it is common practice to use the last component of the directory as the package name, so consider changing your directory structure to match your package names.

Comment: This is a possibility I have tried as well. Unfortunately, I get: cannot load go_poc/plugins: cannot find module providing package go_poc/plugins

Comment: How are you building it? From which directory, using what command?

Comment: go build -buildmode=plugin -o styxBotDetectGrpc.so styxBotDetectGrpc.go

Comment: This works fine for me. Do you have a sane go environment? Is your GOPATH set to .../go? Does styx.pb.go has package name com_styx_proto?

Comment: GOPATH="/Users/CoolUser/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

Comment: @FailedUnitTest, the go tools operate on packages, don’t try to build individual files.

Comment: @JimB this is a Go Plugin, I believe you have to build it in this way.